# The difference between voltage drop and voltage regulation

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage

An ideal voltage drop (VD) is 0%

Similarly, ideal voltage regulation (VR) is 0%

Both give the change in voltage between full load and no load.

The difference I know is that VD is related to cables, while VR is related to sources and loads.

Am I missing something?

Comment: We can't guess what you are missing. Those are two different contexts. Can you give more info what is the question?

Comment: Why do you limit voltage drop to cables? What about components?

Comment: The ideal voltage drop in a blown fuse is 100% -- perhaps you should give us more context.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is context. Voltage drop is measured across loads, for example voltage drop across a length of wire. More current will cause more voltage to be dropped across that length of wire.

Voltage regulation describes the behaviour of a voltage source, where an applied load causes the output voltage of the source to drop. For example in transformers where energy lost in the windings and core increase as the transformer outputs more energy. This causes the output voltage to drop. A comprehensive tutorial on that can be found [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transformer/voltage-regulation.html).

Comment: What about the loads, what is the tolerable voltage range called?

Comment: @OMAR It's called the "tolerable voltage range".

Answer (score 0):

**Voltage drop depends on where you measure it and your reference.**

Your question lacks two things which makes it ambiguous. The reference and the test points.

**Load Regulation % Error is listed in all datasheets for all regulated power supplies.**   It does not include distribution loss from Ohm's Law with associated cables and connectors.

It is measured as follows;

**- % voltage drop for rated load current change, measured at source.**

- it does in fact imply the effective series resistance or "Source resistance" with negative feedback gain as (V1-V2)/I_rated)=R_source  and  Load Regulation error = \$\text{% }Load~Reg.~Error= \dfrac{R_{source}}{R_{load}+R_{source}}\text{x }100\text{ %}=\dfrac{ ΔV}{V_{nom.}} \text{x 100 %} \text{ at rated load}\$

Some supplies might not operate at no load for stability reasons then   ΔV/ ΔI for source resistance is implied.

Load Regulation is at DC and is not the total voltage error which you must  add ripple voltage and step load dynamic error. These high bandwidth errors are done with an ac coupled coax to a 50 ohm load with high BW DSO.